# Conditional display pattern in NSTextField's "Value With Pattern" binding

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I've got the textfield that shows the count of items in `NSArrayController` and count of selected items like this:

> 3 of 5 selected

Also I want to show another pattern when there are no selected items, like:

> 5 items

Is there a way to do this only with Interface Builder without code?

Answer (score 0):

for the first case : `{value2}@ of %{value1}@`

for the second case : `%{value2}@ Items`

Do you want both ?

If yes use both the above.

Comment: can I use any conditions here, such as "if value2 is nil / zero then A else B"?

Comment: @AndreasZollmann: yes you can use conditional statement and even more complex thing to format etc. But not directly, you need to use `NSValueTransformer` and use that in the binding.